# Why is getCode so slow? And is there a better way to find out if an address is a contract?

Tags: web3js, javascript

I've been using Web3's getCode call to find out if an address is a contract, but it significantly slows down my application when I add it, even when I try regular ways to speed up queries (running in parallel, etc.). I am using Infura to access the blockchain. Does anyone know why this happens or of a better way to find out if an address is a contract vs. external? Thanks!

Comment: when you say "slow", how many milliseconds are we talking about?

Comment: To do getCode for  two blocks' worth of transactions takes almost 2 minutes. So, 400ish transactions - 300ish milliseconds per? I'm running the requests in parallel so it could be taking longer for each one, hard to tell.

Comment: That function returns the whole bytecode through http serializing to hexadecimal, a possible workaround is to deploy a contract that only checks the size and you call that contract function (I didn't try it yet can be slower).

Comment: That's a good idea for a workaround. I'll have to give it a try. I figured that the whole bytecode being sent was probably the reason for this being slow, and its just crazy to me that there isn't a more efficient way to check whether an address is a contract. I suppose, reading previous discussions about this issue, that the idea is that we want contract addresses to be treated the same as external addresses, which is why there isn't an easy fix for this yet.